# Username and password not accepted after period of time

Tags: heroku, mean-stack

I apologize in advance for the question since it is very general and unspecific.But I dont have any idea where to start.

I have a MEAN Stack application which is deployed with heroku, and passport js for the authentication.
There are currently 3 User Accounts that use the application on a regular basis. Each Users also uses the application on multiple Computers.

The Problem is that after an unspecific time (between 1 week and 4 weeks) the passwords for all accounts are not working anymore.
To solve the problem I have to deploy the application again to heroku. 
After the deployment everything works as usual.

Any suggestions on where to start looking for the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you saving your user information? Are you using a database? If so, which one?

Comment: Passport.js for authentication and MongoDB Database

Comment: And when authentication stops working, do you see any changes to the data in your database?

Comment: No Data stays the same. After Heroku Re-Deploy everything is back to normal as well.

Comment: Okay, we're going to need a lot more information. Specifically, what does "password not accepted" mean? Are you seeing errors in your browser's console? What about in your back-end logs (check with `heroku logs`)?

Comment: I am using passport.js to verify password. If I start the application local at that time the password is still accepted.There are no errors in console. If password does not match server only returns a 'false'.

Comment: Okay, well if the code is the same and the data is the same I'm really not sure what to say. You need to figure out _why_ your password isn't being accepted. Dig into your Passport.js code, compare hashes, etc. Back up the working data and make _sure_ it hasn't changed when things stop working.

Comment: Thats why I am asking here, because I dont know why it is not accepted. I doubt I will find the problem in Passport.js since it still works locally. I though it might have something to do with heroku, since it works again after re-deploying.